# Why is my code returning IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib
import os
url=urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cow&biw=1242&bih=606&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi21oLAqqzKAhXNjo4KHVs0DkgQ_AUIBigB")
soup=BeautifulSoup(url)
li=soup.find_all('a')
for links in li:
    imgUrl=links.get('href')
    sp1=imgUrl.split('imgurl=')[1]
    sp2=sp1.split('&amp')[0]
    urllib.urlretrieve(sp2)
```

I am trying to download all images from this webpage. The link from which I am downloading is the source code of the google image webpage. It works fine when the code is executed separately for one image but for downloading multiple images using `find_all` it gives an error.

Comment: You need to do a little debugging before asking a question. Try printing out what you get back from `imgUrl.split('imgurl=')`, if that's the line that is failing. If the failing line is the second line, print out the result of `sp1.split('&amp')`.

Answer (score -1):

The following issues in your code need attention:

1) No all imgUrl contains 'imgurl='

2) No all imgUrl contains '&amp'

3) imgUrl may be invalid (e.g, "javascript:void(0)")

With the above considerations in mind, I made some changes to your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib
import os
url=urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cow&biw=1242&bih=606&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi21oLAqqzKAhXNjo4KHVs0DkgQ_AUIBigB")
soup=BeautifulSoup(url)
li=soup.findAll('a', href=True)
for links in li:
    imgUrl=links.get('href')
    if 'imgurl=' in imgUrl:
        imgUrl=imgUrl.split('imgurl=')[1]
    if '&amp' in imgUrl:
        imgUrl=imgUrl.split('&amp')[0]
    try:
        urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl)
    except:
        continue # invalid imgUrl
```